# Include files without #include

Tags: c++, visual-studio

it is possible to include headers files intro visual studio wihtout `#include` preprocessor ?

I mean, i have a .cpp  intro a visual studio project, and i don't want to use #include intro header file or source file. I want to be included automatically.

I mean some Windows header files are included automatically.. Soo i think is possible with files from my project too..

Best regards.

Comment: Why? This is not how C++ works.

Comment: You may try visual studio module, but this is not the final version of module and is intended for evaluation purpose only.

Comment: Some Windows header files are included automatically? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Chris Make a project in visual studio 2013 Who use iterator , make a project in visul studio 2015 Who use iterator.  In 2013 don't include <iterator> it will work, in 2015 you need to include <iterator> ... in 2013 is automatically included.

Comment: Do you include other headers? In order to prove this, you need a code sample that includes absolutely nothing and compiles while using something from `<iterator>` then.

Comment: @Smartx221 Are you sure it's *automatically* included and not included indirectly from another header file you include? System header files are allowed to include other system header files.

Comment: I'm 100% sure. Because is same project , same files, same settings.  It's automtically included.

Comment: @Smartx221, That doesn't preclude a different header changing in 2015 to not include `<iterator>` anymore.

Comment: @Smartx221 are they automatically included, or do they just happen to be indirectly included. In both cases, I would suggest fixing the code.

Comment: Do you not want to type them, or is this just an experiment?

Comment: _"I mean some Windows header files are included automatically"_ This is not impossible (see `-include` in GCC, for example), but it is extremely unlikely that this is happening in your case unless you deliberately did it through your IDE. And if you had, you wouldn't be asking us how. These guys are right: `<iterator>` is being included now through some other header that you `#include`d. It's not "automatic", and it's not "a Windows header file" either. Far from it.

Answer (score 2):

Having some kind of global include files ain't what is recommended in C++ as you can't reason about dependencies anymore. Though it is possible with the Visual Studio compiler by using the [`/FI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) command line option.